# Not able to test getMFAResponse api in yodlee

Tags: yodlee

I am working on an application where I am using the the yodlee IAV rest apis. For the **getMFAResponse** API I am not able to test it for the various MFA authentication types with the data available for the demo accounts for my developer account. When calling the **addItemAndStartVerificationDataRequest1** API it always returns the *refreshStatus* as 4 where as per the *dataflow* diagram we should call the *getMFAResponse* API when the *refreshStatus* returned is 8.

Kindly can somebody suggest a way to test the MFA functionality or provide some sample data with which I can test the *getMFAResponse* and *putMFAResponse* APIs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DAG(Dummy Account Generator) catalog [here](https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/lndhaction.do). This comes with different type of MFA accounts like Security Q/A, CAPTCHA, Security Token and Multilevel. You can use different DAG accounts to test different MFA scenarios.

You can find more details about DAG [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator).